# h5netcdf as default xarray engine

Tags: python, hdf5, python-xarray, netcdf4

The default backend engine for xarray is set to netcdf4 in this [function](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/120e039ddb80510b5fe8be9c20c10362b00c7261/xarray/backends/api.py#L23)

What is the best way to make h5netcdf the default engine in xarray?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to directly set the default engine. Does setting the `engine` key word argument in your `open_dataset` and `to_netcdf` calls not work for some reason?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't currently possible, but we would welcome a pull request to add such as an option via the `xarray.set_options()` interface.

Comment: This seems like a natural step forward given the shared authorship of xarray and h5netcdf. Is there a reason that it has not happened already? Am I missing something?

Comment: @TedHabermann - I think it just hasn't come up yet. Xarray development began before h5netcdf so the legacy default is and will probably remain `netcdf4-python` for a while.

Comment: It does probably makes sense to make h5netcdf the default engine for writing a netCDF4 file if netCDF4-Python is not installed. But yes, we didn't do this at first because h5netcdf was new and experimental (and it still is, to some extent).